# change a pandas datafarme shape and flatten it out

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data source (csv file) which is in this shape:

[image]

Sample raw data is as follow:

```
id  stage   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6
1   base    A                   
1   s1          2   2   4   5
1   s2          3   3   6   7
2   base    AA                  
2   s1          5   3   4   3
2   s2          3   3   2   4
2   s3          2   2   3   6
3   base    B                   
3   s1          4   4   4   5
4   base    BC
```

The first line is an ID and all rows with the same ID are related to the same experiment.

I need to make it flat and change the shape of it when I read it in Pandas to this shape:

[image]

```
id  stage   D1  D2  D3_s1   D4_s1   D5_s1   D6_s1   D3_s2   D4_s2   D5_s2   D6_s2   D3_s3   D4_s3   D5_s3   D6_s3
1   base    A       2   2   4   5   3   3   6   7               
2   base    AA      5   3   4   3   3   3   2   4   2   2   3   6
3   base    B       4   4   4   5                               
4   base    BC
```

What is the best way to do this in Python?

As a C/C++ programmer, I started using several loops to go over each cell and create a new dataframe with the required shape (Still not successful!).

I believe there should be a better way rather than iterating over all rows and cols.

My questions:

What is the best way to do this in Python?

How can I find that D2 is blank and can drop it?

Comment: Please provide data in text format instead of image.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani How can I copy and paste an excel table here?

Comment: copy the excel table and paste it and format as text, same with your output. - its pretty simple to copy it back into a pandas df `pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')` in most cases.

Comment: @Manakin Did as you suggested.

Comment: @mans thanks, good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already read the data into a DataFrame:

- Split it into 2 dataframes: `base` (containing rows with `stage = base`) and `other`
- Unstack the second dataframe and change the column names
- Recombine the two

The code

```
is_base = df['stage'] == 'base'
base = df.loc[is_base, 'id':'D2'].set_index('id')
other =  df.loc[~is_base, ['id','stage','D3','D4','D5','D6']].set_index(['id', 'stage'])

other = other.unstack()
other.columns = other.columns.get_level_values(0) + '_' + other.columns.get_level_values(1)

# Reset index if needed
final = pd.merge(base, other, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: nice one, I think this data structure would benefit from a multi index, shame OP wants it flattened!

Comment: the OP says he's not familiar with pandas so give him some time to realize the benefits of a MultiIndex

Comment: @CodeDifferent You are right and I think I need to spend some times to realize the benefit of using Python and Pandas for data processing :)

Answer (score 1):

As you're a C++ programmer, you'll be happy to know that a lot of the core functions in pandas are actually written in C++ for performance reasons

We can use two filters and a `MultiIndex` by unstacking.

```
s = df1[df1['stage'].ne('base')]


s1 = s.set_index(['id','stage']).stack().unstack([-1,-2])
s1.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in s1.columns] 
# to match your output we flatten the multi index.

print(s1)

   D1_s1 D2_s1 D3_s1 D4_s1 D1_s2 D2_s2 D3_s2 D4_s2 D1_s3 D2_s3 D3_s3 D4_s3
id                                                                        
1      2     2     4     5     3     3     6     7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2      5     3     4     3     3     3     2     4     2     2     3     6
3      4     4     4     5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

then we filter on the `base` value and join based on the `id` column.

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1['stage'].eq('base'), ['id','stage','D1','D2']].set_index('id').join(s1)
```

as for dropping D2 if its blank a simple `if` will do.

```
if df2['D2'].isna().all():
    df2 = df2.drop('D2',1)


print(df2)

   stage  D1 D1_s1 D2_s1 D3_s1 D4_s1 D1_s2 D2_s2 D3_s2 D4_s2 D1_s3 D2_s3  \
id                                                                         
1   base   A     2     2     4     5     3     3     6     7   NaN   NaN   
2   base  AA     5     3     4     3     3     3     2     4     2     2   
3   base   B     4     4     4     5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
4   base  BC   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

   D3_s3 D4_s3  
id              
1    NaN   NaN  
2      3     6  
3    NaN   NaN  
4    NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

You should turn it to `numpy array` and then flatten it and reshape it. like this:

```
data=pd.read_csv(#Your CSV File Name).values
data=data.flatten()
data.reshape(#Your New Shape)
```

Comment: this is a good step but hardly qualifies as an answer

Comment: see [How do i write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I read it. but I think "the best way is simplest way"